# Обрыв выполнения скрипта php

Tags: php, mysqli

Есть  БД в ней 17193 записей, есть столбцы с ссылками, мне надо проверить каждую ссылку на ответ, если ответа нет, то удалить.Скрипт обрывается на 7000, в .htaccses прописал

```
php_value max_execution_time 90000
```

вот сам код

```
<?
include('conect.php');
$q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `Table`") or die(mysql_error());
while ($result=$q->fetch_assoc()):
$id = $result['Id'];
$url= $result['Link_page'];

  if(empty($url))
    return false;
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  curl_close($ch);
  if($http_code>=200 && $http_code<300){
    echo $id."<br>";
  }
  else{
    $db->query("DELETE FROM `Table` WHERE `Id` = $id") or die(mysql_error());
    echo $id." Удален <br>";
  }
endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: Когда мне нужно было обработать 100 000 записей, я разбивал скрипт на пачки по 5000 штук (через `$_GET['page']`). По завершению выполнения редиректил на следующую пачку. К тому же этот скрипт можно выполнить из командной строки сервера, а не запускать из браузера.

Comment: делаю редирект header('Location: delite.php?id=$id');  выдает ошибку Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Comment: Модифицировать заголовки можно только ДО вывода любой информации. Даже если сам php выдаст ошибку на экране, это считается выводом информации. Если вам важно записывать какую-нибудь тестовую информацию, то пишите в файл. Лучше подключить логгер по стандартам psr-3

Answer (score -2):

За раз проверяйте 100 записей например, после этого делайте вызов этого же скрипта через переадресацию с указанием в адресе переменной, например `start_id`, чтобы скрипт использовал ее при выборке очередных 100 записей из базы.